# Blocks doesn't connect to template in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to learn Symfony 4 and it's templates.
When I'm trying to connect blocks with templates like this:

```
// templates/base2.html.twig
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <h2>test</h2>
        {% block blockoftext %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

*(code of block)*

```
// templates/mainpage/index.html.twig
{% extends 'base2.html.twig' %}

{% block blockoftext %}
<h1>And I say: {{ string }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

and then use it like this:

```
// src/Controller/mainpage.php
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class mainpage extends AbstractController
{
      /**
      * @Route("/mainpage")
      */
    public function mainpage()
    {
        $text = 'Hello, world!';
        return $this->render('base2.html.twig', array(
            'string' => $text,
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

the output is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <h2>test</h2>
```

,so, block 'blockoftext' isn't connected. What should I do to get result like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h1>And I say: Hello, world!</h1>
```

?

Comment: You have it slightly backwards. you should be rendering `index.html.twig` instead of base2

Comment: Render `mainpage/index.html.twig` instead of the layout. Isn't that obvious? And follow the `https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html` first, it covers the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
public function mainpage()
{
    $text = 'Hello, world!';
    return $this->render('base2.html.twig', array(
        'string' => $text,
    ));
}
```

Change the return to be

```
return $this->render('index.html.twig', array(
    'string' => $text,
));
```

The index file is an extension of the base2. not the other way around. So `index` will include`base2`, but `base2` will not include anything from `index`